# Failure to find org.primefaces.themes

Tags: maven, primefaces

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.edu</groupId>
<artifactId>MorpheusTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>MorpheusTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>morpheus</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakartaee}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Error:

Failed to execute goal on project MorpheusTest: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.edu:MorpheusTest:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.primefaces.themes:morpheus:jar:2.0.1 in http://repository.primefaces.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of prime-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I have seen other answers on stack overflow that suggest to add this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

However, I still have the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we visit the https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/, there is no artifact named `morpheus` which is the root cause of the `Failure to find org.primefaces.themes:morpheus:jar:2.0.1 ...` error.

Furthermore, the https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/ host only the `community theme` (open source) which is mentioned at https://www.primefaces.org/themes/, while the `morpheus` (https://www.primefaces.org/layouts/morpheus) is a commercial theme which we have to buy from the Primefaces company (https://www.primefaces.org/store/) and does not publish in any repository.

Comment: To add on top of this answer, if you bought that theme you need to download the jar and add to your project. Also there is no need to use both all themes and a specific one. just the specific one is sufficient.